# PHP html Styling

Tags: php, css, html

> Im trying to make the div col-lg-7 close, but the div row is closing instead.  I don't know why its happening.  It loops through fine on the first time, but when it loops the second time, It gets thrown out of place. Im trying to make it work for every time that it loops around.

My site is http://nathanielmignotte.ca/Work/CottageSite/cottageRentals.php

```
Print "<div class=row>";
Print "<div class=col-lg-7>";

while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        {  
          Print "<p>".$info['images']."</p>";
          Print "<br>";
          Print "</div>";
          Print '<div class="col-lg-5">';
          Print '<ul class="nobullets marginUl">';
          Print "<li>".$info['Cottagename']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['Addressstreet']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['Address_City']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['BedroomsNo']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['Facilities']."</li>";
          Print "<li>".$info['Availability']."</li>";
          Print "<li>".$info['Pricepernight']."</li>";
          Print "<div>".$info['View_Gallery']."</div>";
          Print "</div>";
        }
      Print "</ul>";
      Print "</div>";
```

Comment: The first </div> at the top of your while loop is closing lg-7, which can only be closed once. So when your loop runs again, it closes 'row', and so on, closing an earlier div each time the loop runs if they exist. What is it you intended that first </div> to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Print "<div class=row>";


while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) 
        {  
          Print "<div class=col-lg-7>";
          Print "<p>".$info['images']."</p>";
          Print "<br>";
          Print "</div>";
          Print '<div class="col-lg-5">';
          Print '<ul class="nobullets marginUl">';
          Print "<li>".$info['Cottagename']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['Addressstreet']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['Address_City']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['BedroomsNo']."</li>"; 
          Print "<li>".$info['Facilities']."</li>";
          Print "<li>".$info['Availability']."</li>";
          Print "<li>".$info['Pricepernight']."</li>";
          Print "<div>".$info['View_Gallery']."</div>";
          Print "</ul>";
          Print "</div>";

        }

      Print "</div>";
```

try this.

Answer (score 1):

The produced html is invalid. Try

```
echo '<div class=row>',
        '<div class=col-lg-7>';
while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {  
    echo   '<p>',$info['images'],'</p>',
           '<div class="col-lg-5">',
              '<ul class="nobullets marginUl">',
                 '<li>',$info['Cottagename'],'</li>',
                 '<li>',$info['Addressstreet'],'</li>',
                 '<li>',$info['Address_City'],'</li>',
                 '<li>',$info['BedroomsNo'],'</li>',
                 '<li>',$info['Facilities'],'</li>',
                 '<li>',$info['Availability'],'</li>',
                 '<li>',$info['Pricepernight'],'</li>',
              '</ul>',
              '<div>',$info['View_Gallery'],'</div>';
           '</div>';
}
echo    '</div>',
     '</div>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the first of this line.

```
  Print "</div>";
```

Comment: okay, I removed it, but now its gets pushed down underneath it, not beside it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Why not cut down on half the `print`/`echo` use?

```
<div class=row>
    <div class=col-lg-7>
<?php   while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { ?>
        <p><?php echo $info['images']; ?></p>
        <br>
        <div class="col-lg-5">
            <ul class="nobullets marginUl">
                <li><?php echo $info['Cottagename']; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $info['Addressstreet']; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $info['Address_City']; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $info['BedroomsNo']; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $info['Facilities']; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $info['Availability']; ?></li>
                <li><?php echo $info['Pricepernight']; ?></li>
            </ul>
            <div><?php echo $info['View_Gallery']; ?></div>
        </div>
<?php   } ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php 
    $print = '';
    $print .= '
        <div class=row>';
    while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
        $print .= '
            <div class=col-lg-7>
                <p>' . $info['images'] . '</p><br>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <ul class="nobullets marginUl">
                    <li>' . $info['Cottagename']   . '</li>
                    <li>' . $info['Addressstreet'] . '</li>
                    <li>' . $info['Address_City']  . '</li>
                    <li>' . $info['BedroomsNo']    . '</li>
                    <li>' . $info['Facilities']    . '</li>
                    <li>' . $info['Availability']  . '</li>
                    <li>' . $info['Pricepernight'] . '</li>
                    <div>' . $info['View_Gallery']  . '</div>
                </ul>
            </div>';
    }
    $print .= '
        </div>';
?>
<?php echo $print ?>
```